# How to compile with LLVM/Clang via API with no executable invocation?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I'd like to compile source file to LLVM IR in my demo app with LLVM/Clang API with no `clang` executable invocation. It seems that `Driver` still uses executable to execute `Compilation` (i've used slightly modified [example](http://fdiv.net/2012/08/15/compiling-code-clang-api))

```
string clangPath = "clang";

string inputPath = "../test/hello_world.cpp";
string outputPath = "hello_world.ll";

// "clang -S -emit-llvm ../test/hello_world.cpp -v"
vector<const char *> args;
args.push_back(clangPath.c_str());
args.push_back("-S");
args.push_back("-emit-llvm");
args.push_back(inputPath.c_str());
args.push_back("-v");

// ...
```

As you can see it prints actions and compile seems to require `clang` executable path:

```
MBA-Anton:build asmirnov$ ./clang_ir
Starting ----
making driver
making compilation
clang version 3.4 (branches/release_34 198679)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
printing actions:
0: input, "../test/hello_world.cpp", c++
1: preprocessor, {0}, c++-cpp-output
2: compiler, {1}, ir
3: bind-arch, "x86_64", {2}, ir
Done ----
 "clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0 -emit-llvm -disable-free -main-file-name hello_world.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 224.1 -v -coverage-file /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/clang_jni/mac/build/hello_world.ll -resource-dir ../lib/clang/3.4 -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/clang_jni/mac/build -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 100 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.9.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o hello_world.ll -x c++ ../test/hello_world.cpp
error: unable to execute command: Executable "clang" doesn't exist!
```

Does it really need clang path and how can i do compilation to LLVM IR via LLVM/Clang API with no executable invocation? If it's not available with current API how can i modify API to use static lib instead of executable?

Comment: You may want to look at the ROOT "cling" project for an example of Clang with a JIT backend.

Comment: I've find out that it really uses `clang`executable out-of-box. Does cling do compilation to LLVM IR with no executable invocation?